How do I deduce one template parameter from another?
I have my functor class that can encapsulate function/member function and arbitrary count of function parameters.
#include <tuple>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

template <class PARENT>
class FunctorHandlerBase
{
public:
    typedef typename PARENT::TRET RTYPE;
    typedef typename PARENT::TUP ARGS;

    virtual RTYPE operator()(ARGS) { return RTYPE(0); };
};

template <class PARENT, typename MFUN>
class FunctorHandler : public FunctorHandlerBase<PARENT> {
public:
    typedef typename PARENT::TRET RTYPE;
    typedef typename PARENT::TUP ARGS;
    FunctorHandler(MFUN pfun)
        : pFun(pfun)
    {}

    virtual ~FunctorHandler() {};

    virtual RTYPE operator()(ARGS args) {
        return callPrivate(args, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<decltype(args)>>{});
    }

private:
    template<class Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
    RTYPE callPrivate(Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return (*pFun)(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))...);
    }

    MFUN pFun;
};

template <class PARENT, class POBJ, typename MFUN>
class MFunctorHandler : public FunctorHandlerBase<PARENT> {
public:
    typedef typename PARENT::TRET RTYPE;
    typedef typename PARENT::TUP ARGS;
    MFunctorHandler(const POBJ &pobj, MFUN pfun)
        : pObj(pobj), pFun(pfun)
    {}

    virtual ~MFunctorHandler() {};

    virtual RTYPE operator()(ARGS args) {
        return callPrivate(args, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<decltype(args)>>{});
    }

private:
    template<class Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
    RTYPE callPrivate(Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return ((*pObj).*pFun)(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))...);
    }

    POBJ pObj;
    MFUN pFun;

};

template <typename RTYPE = void>
class FunctorBase
{
public:
    virtual RTYPE operator()() {
        return RTYPE(0);
    }
};

template <typename RTYPE = void, class... Args>
class Functor : public FunctorBase<RTYPE>
{
public:
    typedef RTYPE TRET;
    typedef typename std::tuple<Args ...> TUP;

    template<typename MFUN>
    Functor(MFUN pfun, Args&&... args)
        : mArgs(args...)
    {
        pImpl = QSharedPointer<FunctorHandlerBase<Functor>>(new FunctorHandler<Functor, MFUN>(pfun));
    }

    template<class POBJ, typename MFUN>
    Functor(const POBJ &pobj, MFUN pfun, Args&&... args)
        : mArgs(args...)
    {
        pImpl = QSharedPointer<FunctorHandlerBase<Functor>>(new MFunctorHandler<Functor, POBJ, MFUN>(pobj, pfun));
    }

    RTYPE operator()()
    {
        return (*pImpl)(mArgs);
    }

    std::tuple<Args ...> mArgs;
private:
    QSharedPointer<FunctorHandlerBase<Functor>> pImpl;
};

template<typename RTYPE, class POBJ, typename MFUN, class... Args>
FunctorBase<RTYPE> *Create(const POBJ &pobj, MFUN pfun, Args&& ...args) {
    return new Functor<RTYPE, Args...>(pobj, pfun, std::forward<Args...>(args)...);
}

class B
{
public:
    B(){};

    bool voidF() {
        return true;
    }
    bool printInt(int x) {
        std::cout << "print int:" << x;
        return true;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    B *b = new B;
    auto *fb = Create<bool>(b, &B::printInt, 100);

    std::cout << "function result" << (*fb)();
}


Can I deduce function return type from pointer to function in FunctorBase::Create() function? To change "auto *fb = Create<bool>(b, &B::printInt, 100)" to "auto *fb = Create(b, &B::printInt, 100)".

Can I create Functor base class without any template parameters? I want to pack some functions with different return types in vector and get function return type by std::is_same_v. Now I can pack only functions with a same return type.



Notice there exist std::function.

This doesn't compile: ‘QSharedPointer’ does not name a type

@TobySpeight sorry, I'm using Qt, I forgot to change it to std::shared_ptr before publish this question

The example in the question is far from minimal, and is uncompilable anyway, but it seems that you're looking for std::invoke_result:
template<class Pobj, typename Mfun, class... Args>  // NOTE 1
auto *Create(const Pobj &pobj, Mfun pfun, Args&& ...args) {
    return new Functor<std::invoke_result_t<Mfun, Pobj, Args...>, Args...>(pobj, pfun, std::forward<Args...>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    B *b = new B;
    FunctorBase<bool> *fb = Create(b, &B::printInt, 100);
    std::cout << "function result: " << (*fb)() << '\n';
    delete fb;  // NOTE 2
    delete b;
}



I renamed the template arguments to look less like preprocessor macros.
Please do provide a virtual destructor in the base class - without that, you have a serious memory bug!


Thank you! Can you explain me, why I'll have memory leak without virtual destructor of FunctorBase? I don't have any data I need to delete by myself in Functor.

And why you printed "auto *Create" instead of "auto Create"? Return type of Create(...) function is pointer...

auto *Create() is clearer that a pointer is returned, and is part of $DAY_JOB's style guide.  The memory leak is clear - Functor has mArgs and pImpl which don't get destructed by ~FunctorBase().  Just run this version of the code under Valgrind and you'll see it.  And you'll see that virtual ~FunctorBase() = default fixes it.

Understood, it's becouse FunctorBase is the base class and it must have virtual destructor, am I right?



Can I deduce function return type from pointer to function in FunctorBase::Create function? To change auto *fb = Create<bool>(b, &B::printInt, 100) to auto *fb = Create(b, &B::printInt, 100).


You might use decltype:
template<class POBJ, typename MFUN, class... Args>
auto Create(const POBJ &pobj, MFUN pfun, Args&& ...args)
-> FunctorBase<decltype((pobj->*pfun)(std::forward<Args...>(args)...))>*
{
    return new Functor<decltype((pobj->*pfun)(std::forward<Args...>(args)...)), Args...>(pobj, pfun, std::forward<Args...>(args)...);
}

Demo


Can I create Functor base class without any template parameters? I want to pack some functions with different return types in vector and get function return type by std::is_same_v. Now I can pack only functions with a same return type.


You might use common return type as void, but then it seems it is useless.
Returning std::variant or std::any might be an alternative, but unsure what you want to do exactly...
